# How to allocate memory from a particular DRAM in the system?

Tags: memory, memory-mapping, main-memory

I want to read and write data from a particular DRAM in my system. I know that I can list available DRAMs using  decode-dimms command. But I didn't find a detailed explanation that how actually this can be done, And little confused how VA -> PA - > DRAM mapping is done. Please help me with this.

Comment: Virtual memory mapping is handled by the operating system.  What OS are you using?  Or are you on the bare metal?  Also, what CPU architecture, system type, etc?

Comment: @NateEldredge Linux on Arm